# Pass Blade Component Parameters from Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass some parameters to a blade component from an array.

Here is how I pass them:

```
@php
    $buttons = array(
        array(
            "type" => "button",
            "content" => "Button 1",
            "leadingIcon" => "plus",
            "trailingIcon" => "plus"
        ),
        array(
            "type" => "button",
            "content" => "Button 2",
            "leadingIcon" => "plus",
            "trailingIcon" => "plus"
        ),
        array(
            "type" => "button",
            "content" => "Button 3",
            "leadingIcon" => "plus",
            "trailingIcon" => "plus"
        ),
        array(
            "type" => "button",
            "content" => "Button 4",
            "leadingIcon" => "plus",
            "trailingIcon" => "plus"
        ),
    );
@endphp

<x-buttons-group :buttons="$buttons" size="small" style="secondary" fullWidth="false"/>
```

Now, inside the `<x-buttons-group>` component I am trying to do a loop with `<x-buttons-button>` that needs a parameters I just passed with the array.

Here is a source code for the :

```
<div class="{!!$fullWidth!!} flex flex-row space-x-0 overflow-hidden rounded-lg border {!!$borderColor!!}">
    <ul class="flex w-full flex-row space-x-0">
        @foreach($buttons as $button)
        <li class="children:border-0 children:rounded-none w-full border-r {!!$borderRightColor!!} last:border-r-0">
            <x-buttons-button @foreach($button as $key => $value) :{!!$key!!}="{!!$value!!}" @endforeach />
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is that when I view the source of the page this is what I get:

```
<div class="flex w-auto flex-row space-x-0 overflow-hidden rounded-lg border border-gray-300">
    <ul class="flex w-full flex-row space-x-0">
        <li class="children:border-0 children:rounded-none w-full border-r border-r-gray-300 last:border-r-0">
            <x-buttons-button :type="button" :content="Button 1" :leadingIcon="plus" :trailingIcon="plus" />
        </li>
        <li class="children:border-0 children:rounded-none w-full border-r border-r-gray-300 last:border-r-0">
            <x-buttons-button :type="button" :content="Button 2" :leadingIcon="plus" :trailingIcon="plus" />
        </li>
        <li class="children:border-0 children:rounded-none w-full border-r border-r-gray-300 last:border-r-0">
            <x-buttons-button :type="button" :content="Button 3" :leadingIcon="plus" :trailingIcon="plus" />
        </li>
        <li class="children:border-0 children:rounded-none w-full border-r border-r-gray-300 last:border-r-0">
            <x-buttons-button :type="button" :content="Button 4" :leadingIcon="plus" :trailingIcon="plus" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So... Instead of the component being rendered, it passes a raw line of text like `<x-buttons-button :type="button" :content="Button 4" :leadingIcon="plus" :trailingIcon="plus" />`.

Any idea about how I can solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to have something like `@foreach(...)<x-buttons-button...>@endforeach`?

Comment: @brombeer this will not work because I need `@foreach` for the component parameters. I already have another `@foreach` above the `<li>` inside the `<x-buttons-group>` component source code.

Comment: You can't use blade @... inside the component tag

Comment: Why loop?  Don't you just pass the $button into the component as `:button="$button"`

Comment: The first loop is used to determine the number of buttons passed inside <x-buttons-group>. The second loop is used to get all parameters for each button <x-buttons-button>.

Comment: How is this component being registered? I suspect if you had just passed the array directly to the `x-buttons-button` component it would be a much cleaner solution but it's hard to say without more context. Also, variable assignments belong in your controller, not a `@php` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the way to do it. The answer was `Blade::render`.

Here is the new source for `<x-buttons-group>`:

```
<div class="{!! $fullWidth !!} {!! $borderColor !!} flex flex-row space-x-0 overflow-hidden rounded-lg border">
    <ul class="flex w-full flex-row space-x-0">
        @foreach ($buttons as $params)
            <li class="children:border-0 children:rounded-none {!! $borderRightColor !!} w-full border-r last:border-r-0">
                @php
                    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                        $param .= ' '.$key.'="'.$value.'"';
                    }
                    echo Blade::render('<x-buttons-button name="name" '.$param.' />');
                @endphp
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```